# Dates are not equal while using timeIntervalSince1970

Tags: swift, date, comparison

I've just run the code below several times and see that sometimes date1 and date2 are equal but sometimes are not.

```
    let date1 = Date()
    let date2 = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: date1.timeIntervalSince1970)

    print(date1)
    print(date2)
    print(date1.timeIntervalSince1970)
    print(date2.timeIntervalSince1970)
    print(date1 == date2)
```

So sometimes I get:

```
2019-03-22 05:52:30 +0000
2019-03-22 05:52:30 +0000

1553233950.498001
1553233950.498001

false
```

These dates look the same but comparison tells me they are different. The problem is that the date2 is slightly different from the date1. To prove it I can write:

```
print(date1.timeIntervalSince(date2))
```

and get:

-1.1920928955078125e-07

**So it there any way to translate date1 to number and then back to date2 which is equal to date1?**

Comment: What does mean - `ranslate date1 to number and then back to date2 which is equal to date1?`

Comment: If the smallest unit of time you care about is seconds, just do `abs(date1.timeIntervalSince(date2)) < 1` to check if they are equal.

Comment: @Sweeper I care about the smallest unit.

Comment: @AmirKhan "translate date1 to number and then back" means converting variable of Date type to Double type and then back and you get exactly the same value as at the beginning.

Comment: `converting variable of Date type to Double type and then back and you get exactly the same value as at the beginning` - It takes micro seconds which cause changes in timestamp. That's why you are getting difference in Dates.

Comment: @AmirKhan so there is no way to translate date to double and back without losing these microseconds?

Comment: @Roman can you please explain me what and why you want to operate on `Date1` ? So that I can help you out with possible alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the usage of `timeIntervalSince1970`. If you use this, the `Date` implementation will do some `Double` calculations to align it to the reference date (2001-01-01).

If you use `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` instead, this will be used directly, and your code should work then:

```
for i in 1...200000 {
    let date1 = Date()
    let date2 = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: date1.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)
    if (date1 != date2) {
        // never called on my machine:
        let delta = date1.timeIntervalSince(date2)
        print("\(i): \(delta)")
    }
}
```

---

For your information, here the interesting parts of `struct Date` implementation on https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/Date.swift - you see the calculation done in the first `init`:

```
public struct Date : ReferenceConvertible, Comparable, Equatable {

    fileprivate var _time: TimeInterval
    public static let timeIntervalBetween1970AndReferenceDate: TimeInterval = 978307200.0

    public init(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval) {
        self.init(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: timeIntervalSince1970 - Date.timeIntervalBetween1970AndReferenceDate)
    }
    public init(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate ti: TimeInterval) {
        _time = ti
    }
}
```

Comment: Andreas Oetjen That's exactly what I need. Thank you! I see when using "timeIntervalSince1970" we can lose some precision by subtracting one value from another.